# How do I avoid incurring in lifetime issues when refactoring a function?

Tags: rust, async-await

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f55d80dce14020b7a6d05c97ff66f38) if you want to jump directly into the code.

#### Problem

I'm trying to implement a function `filter_con<T, F>(v: Vec<T>, predicate: F)` that allows concurrent filter on a `Vec`, via `async` predicates.

That is, instead of doing:

```rust
let arr = vec![...];
let arr_filtered = join_all(arr.into_iter().map(|it| async move {
    if some_getter(&it).await > some_value {
        Some(it)
    } else {
        None
    }
}))
.await
.into_iter()
.filter_map(|it| it)
.collect::<Vec<T>>()
```

every time I need to filter for a `Vec`, I want to be able to:

```rust
let arr = vec![...];
let arr_filtered = filter_con(arr, |it| async move { 
  some_getter(&it).await > some_value 
}).await
```

#### Tentative implementation

I've extracted the function into its own but I am incurring in lifetime issues

```rust
async fn filter_con<T, B, F>(arr: Vec<T>, predicate: F) -> Vec<T>
where
    F: FnMut(&T) -> B,
    B: futures::Future<Output = bool>,
{
    join_all(arr.into_iter().map(|it| async move {
        if predicate(&it).await {
            Some(it)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }))
    .await
    .into_iter()
    .filter_map(|p| p)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
```

I don't know what I'm moving out of predicate?

For more details, see the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f55d80dce14020b7a6d05c97ff66f38).

Comment: OK so I think the FnMut is the `map()` argument. No idea if we can cast it, since we're no modifying anything here...

Comment: After some discussion on Discord, [here's as close as I can get](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=52579bd0067dfb1bb0da9a32b729127b). I believe the remaining error is solvable but I'm not seeing the matrix at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to make the predicate an `FnOnce`, because, if you have 10 items in your `Vec`, you'll need to call the predicate 10 times, but an `FnOnce` only guarantees it can be called once, which could lead to something like this:

```rust
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
let has_drop_impl = String::from("hello");

filter_con(vec, |&i| async {
  drop(has_drop_impl);
  i < 5
}
```

So `F` must be either an `FnMut` or an `Fn`. The standard library `Iterator::filter` takes an `FnMut`, though this can be a source of confusion (it is the captured variables of the *closure* that need a mutable reference, not the elements of the iterator).

Because the predicate is an `FnMut`, any caller needs to be able to get an `&mut F`. For `Iterator::filter`, this can be used to do something like this:

```rust
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
let mut count = 0;

vec.into_iter().filter(|&x| {
  count += 1;  // this line makes the closure an `FnMut`
  x < 2
})
```

However, by sending the iterator to `join_all`, you are essentially allowing your async runtime to schedule these calls as it wants, potentially at the same time, which would cause an aliased `&mut T`, which is always undefined behaviour. This issue has a slightly more cut down version of the same issue https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/69446.

I'm still not 100% on the details, but it seems the compiler is being conservative here and doesn't even let you create the closure in the first place to prevent soundness issues.

I'd recommend making your function only accept `Fn`s. This way, your runtime is free to call the function however it wants. This does means that your closure cannot have mutable state, but this is unlikely to be a problem in a tokio application. For the counting example, the "correct" solution is to use an `AtomicUsize` (or equivalent), which allows mutation via shared reference. If you're referencing mutable state in your `filter` call, it should be thread safe, and thread safe data structures generally allow mutation via shared reference.

Given that restriction, the following gives the answer you expect:

```
async fn filter_con<T, B, F>(arr: Vec<T>, predicate: F) -> Vec<T>
where
    F: Fn(&T) -> B,
    B: Future<Output = bool>,
{
    join_all(arr.into_iter().map(|it| async {
        if predicate(&it).await {
            Some(it)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }))
    .await
    .into_iter()
    .filter_map(|p| p)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=44be6e1e2598384124e54759c3f79305)

Comment: Thank you @cameron1024! I looked up the `Fn`/`FnOnce`/`FnMut` distinction and your explanation is on point! However in here you're using using the fact that the vector's item is Copy, which was there just for simplicity (see comment above declaration). I've edited the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f55d80dce14020b7a6d05c97ff66f38) to better reflect that.